# Error during Pdal installation

Tags: python, linux, pip, point-clouds

I am installing Pdal library in linux(ubuntu) using: `pip install pdal` command and getting these errors:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1777:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from pdal/libpdalpython.cpp:487:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
pdal/libpdalpython.cpp:489:32: **fatal error:** pdal/plang/Array.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I searched solution for this error but not get anything related to it.

Comment: Please expand on how you have installed PDAL first, as the `pip install pdal` command only installs the bindings. Also, which version of PDAL are you installing (or attempting to install)?

Comment: okay. I installed PDAL 1.5.0 through osGeo4w then i take clone of PDAL and try **pip install pdal** for my python code. I am a beginner to all these things. Will you please provide me a steps to install PDAL in ubuntu. I read PDAL docs for installation but i didn't get much to install it properly.

Comment: I'd suggest looking [here](https://www.pdal.io/development/compilation/unix.html) for Unix compilation instructions.

There is still some confusion here as you have indicated using OSGeo4W which is Windows only as well as needing this to be on Ubuntu. Which is it?

Is running with the Docker image an option for you? It is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually i install osGeo4w in ubuntu using wine.

Comment: Try installing the resulting package of this command before re-runing `pip`: `apt-cache search pdal`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a viable solution for you (which was unavailable when you first asked) would be to install via Conda rather than pip. See https://pdal.io/download.html#conda for more details. Our Conda package will install both PDAL and the Python extension and is supported on Linux, Windows, and Mac.